# Chat archive for machine learning

Tags: machine-learning

Hiho, currently I'm trying to use machine learning to learn dialogues and conversations. Unfortunately I'm not able to find big archives of chat logs.
Do you know some public archives in english and german language?

Obviously, chat logs means something like this:

```
    Partner 1: hey, how are you?
    Partner 2: I'm fine, you?
    Partner 1: fine as well.
    Partner 1: wanna go to the gym?
    Partner 2: yeah, lets go
```

for example. doesn't matter if there are more than 2 chat partners.

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can find many IRC logs on the websites below. The first has actual raw log files, probably that's what you're looking for.

- http://people.freedesktop.org/~cbrill/dri-log/index.php
- http://irclogs.jackgrigg.com/irc.freenode.net/miro/
- http://irc.projecthydra.org/

Comment: thanks for the quick answer, but i'm just searching a very large file without manual effort. the layout may be of any kind, I could parse it. but I'm not able to finde a page where some big files are available for download